# How to nameref multiple labels simultaneously?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref, nameref

On this example, I use `\cref{first,second}` and `cleveref` correctly labels them:
[image]

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\namecref{first,second}

\chapter{First}
\label{first}

\chapter{Second}
\label{second}

\end{document}
```

But, if I use `\nameref{first,second}`, then, it gives me only `??` instead of `First and Second`.

How can I use `\nameref` with multiple labels as `\cref`?

Comment: the cleveref manual states "Note that [namecref] can only be passed a single reference name; they do not accept multi-references like \cref.  (Passing multiple references to these commands  would  make  little  sense  if  the  references  had  different types,  and is redundant if they have the same type.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code. Note that `user` is your current display name; you should probably replace the `user` prefix in the code with something more likely to be unique in order to be sure not to conflict with other unrelated code that might exist using the same prefix.

```latex
% The code below automatically adapts to the selected language.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% #1: variant (cref, Cref, crefs or Crefs)
% #2: reference name (label)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_name_cref:nn #1#2
  { \use:c { name #1 } {#2} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_cref:nn { xV }

% #1: boolean expression (true: disable hyperlink)
% #2: reference name (label)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_name_ref:nn #1#2
  { \bool_if:nTF {#1} { \nameref* } { \nameref } {#2} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_ref:nn { nV }

\seq_new:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq
\seq_new:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq
\int_new:N \l__user_name_refs_nbrefs_int
\tl_new:N \l__user_name_refs_firstref_tl

% #1: boolean expression (true: start with capitalized letter, as in \Cref)
% #2: boolean expression (true: disable hyperlinks)
% #3: comma list of refs
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_name_refs:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq {#3}
    \int_set:Nn \l__user_name_refs_nbrefs_int
                { \seq_count:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq }
    \seq_get_left:NN \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq \l__user_name_refs_firstref_tl

    % (section, Section, sections or Sections) or (theorem, Theorem, ...) or...
    \user_name_cref:xV
      { \bool_if:nTF {#1} { C } { c }
        ref
       \int_compare:nNnTF { \l__user_name_refs_nbrefs_int } > { 1 } { s } { } }
     \l__user_name_refs_firstref_tl
    \nobreakspace

    % Now print the references.
    \seq_clear:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq
      {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq
                          { \user_name_ref:nn {#2} {##1} }
      }
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq { \crefpairconjunction }
                  { \crefmiddleconjunction } { \creflastconjunction }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_refs:nnn { nx }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_name_refs:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \user_name_refs:nxn {#1}
      { \IfBooleanTF {#2} { \c_true_bool } { \c_false_bool } }
      {#3}
  }

% “Start in lower case” variant. With star: disable hyperlinks.
% #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \nameRefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:Nnn \c_false_bool {#1} {#2}
  }

% “Start in upper case” variant. With star: disable hyperlinks.
% #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \NameRefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:Nnn \c_true_bool {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

References:
\begin{itemize}
\item With one reference and hyperlink: \nameRefs{first} (we'll disable
  hyperlinks from now on, because their default appearance is hideous and they
  don't behave very well across line breaks);
\item With one reference: \nameRefs*{first};
\item With two references: \nameRefs*{first, second};
\item With three references: \nameRefs*{first, second, third};
\item With four references: \nameRefs*{first, second, third, fourth};
\item Capitalized variant: \NameRefs*{first, second, third, fourth};
\item etc.
\end{itemize}

% This is a cref command; beware that spaces are not ignored after the commas!
For comparison, the \verb|\cref| command: \cref{first,second,third,fourth}.

\section{First section}
\label{first}

\section{Second section}
\label{second}

\section{Third section}
\label{third}

\section{Fourth section}
\label{fourth}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I wrote a new variation of this here: [Undefined control sequence while adding a new parameter to a existing \ExplSyntaxOn code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515877/undefined-control-sequence-while-adding-a-new-parameter-to-a-existing-explsynta)