# Undefined control sequence while adding a new parameter to a existing \ExplSyntaxOn code

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref, nameref

I am fixing my command `\fullref`, which internally uses `\nameref` and does not support multiple labels to be used simultaneously. However, on the question [How to nameref multiple labels simultaneously?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505351/how-to-nameref-multiple-labels-simultaneously), it is presented a fixed version of `\nameref` which support multiple labels simultaneously.

The answer on that question, offers 2 variants of `\nameref`, but for my `\fullref` command, I need a new variant which allows me to omit the reference label name as `Figure` in `Figure My Caption`.

Editing the answer on the question [How to nameref multiple labels simultaneously?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505351), I managed to create this new variant, beyond the 2 variants already on the answer. Resulting in the following 3 variants of `\nameref` command:

```latex
% “Start in lower case” variant. With star: disable hyperlinks.
% Does put the label name, i.e., Figure My Figure. #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \namerefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:NNnn \c_true_bool \c_false_bool {#1} {#2}
  }

% “Start in upper case” variant. With star: disable hyperlinks.
% Does put the label name, i.e., Figure My Figure. #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \Namerefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:NNnn \c_true_bool \c_true_bool {#1} {#2}
  }

% “Start in lower case” variant. With star: disable hyperlinks.
% Does NOT put the label name, i.e., My Figure. #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \nameRefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:NNnn \c_false_bool \c_false_bool {#1} {#2}
  }
```

The changes I did were just adding a new boolean parameter as the first parameter on the `\__user_name_refs:NNnn` function, and pass this parameter forward to the function `\user_name_refs:nnxn`, and use it inside the function `\user_name_refs:nnxn` to not print the `\nameref` label name as `Figure`.

If the first parameter of the function `\user_name_refs:nnxn` is `true`, then, the reference label as `Figure` will be printed/output. If it is `false`, then, it prints nothing, i.e., no `Figure` label.

```latex
    \bool_if:nTF {#1}
    {
      % (section, Section, sections or Sections) or (theorem, Theorem, ...) or...
      \user_name_cref:xV
        { \bool_if:nTF {#2} { C } { c }
          ref
         \int_compare:nNnTF { \l__user_name_refs_nbrefs_int } > { 1 } { s } { } }
       \l__user_name_refs_firstref_tl
      \nobreakspace
    }{}
```

So far, I have edited all the code which should be enough to make these 3 `\nameref` variants above to work. But I cannot make it compile as latex throws this error:

```
(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\omscmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\__user_name_refs:NNnn ...4->\user_name_refs:nnxn
                                                  {#1}{#2}{\IfBooleanTF {#3}...
l.114 ...reference and hyperlink: \nameRefs{first}
                                                   (we'll disable
```

I do not know very well new extended syntax and I am probably missing something quite simple. Can you find what did I forget to add with my changes?

```latex
% The code below automatically adapts to the selected language.
\documentclass[english]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\OnehalfSpacing

\ExplSyntaxOn

% #1: variant (cref, Cref, crefs or Crefs)
% #2: reference name (label)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_name_cref:nn #1#2
  { \use:c { name #1 } {#2} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_cref:nn { xV }

% #1: boolean expression (true: disable hyperlink)
% #2: reference name (label)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_name_ref:nn #1#2
  { \bool_if:nTF {#1} { \nameref* } { \nameref } {#2} }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_ref:nn { nV }

\seq_new:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq
\seq_new:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq
\int_new:N \l__user_name_refs_nbrefs_int
\tl_new:N \l__user_name_refs_firstref_tl

% #1: boolean expression (true: Does put the label name, i.e., Figure My Figure)
% #2: boolean expression (true: start with capitalized letter, as in \Cref)
% #3: boolean expression (true: disable hyperlinks)
% #4: comma list of refs
\cs_new_protected:Npn \user_name_refs:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq {#4}
    \int_set:Nn \l__user_name_refs_nbrefs_int
                { \seq_count:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq }
    \seq_get_left:NN \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq \l__user_name_refs_firstref_tl

    \bool_if:nTF {#1}
    {
      % (section, Section, sections or Sections) or (theorem, Theorem, ...) or...
      \user_name_cref:xV
        { \bool_if:nTF {#2} { C } { c }
          ref
         \int_compare:nNnTF { \l__user_name_refs_nbrefs_int } > { 1 } { s } { } }
       \l__user_name_refs_firstref_tl
      \nobreakspace
    }{}

    % Now print the references.
    \seq_clear:N \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq
      {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq
                          { \user_name_ref:nn {#3} {##2} }
      }
    \seq_use:Nnnn \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq { \crefpairconjunction }
                  { \crefmiddleconjunction } { \creflastconjunction }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_refs:nnnn { nx }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_name_refs:NNnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \user_name_refs:nnxn {#1}
      {#2}
      { \IfBooleanTF {#3} { \c_true_bool } { \c_false_bool } }
      {#4}
  }

% “Start in lower case” variant.
% Does put the label name, i.e., Figure My Figure.
% With star: disable hyperlinks.
% #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \namerefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:NNnn \c_true_bool \c_false_bool {#1} {#2}
  }

% “Start in upper case” variant.
% Does put the label name, i.e., Figure My Figure.
% With star: disable hyperlinks.
% #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \Namerefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:NNnn \c_true_bool \c_true_bool {#1} {#2}
  }

% “Start in lower case” variant.
% Does NOT put the label name, i.e., My Figure.
% With star: disable hyperlinks.
% #2: comma list of refs
\NewDocumentCommand \nameRefs { s m }
  {
    \__user_name_refs:NNnn \c_false_bool \c_false_bool {#1} {#2}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\Cref{#1}: \nameRefs{#1}}

\begin{document}

\fullref{first,second,third,fourth}.

\namerefs{first,second,third,fourth}.

\Namerefs{first,second,third,fourth}.

\nameRefs{first,second,third,fourth}.

\section{First section}
\label{first}

\section{Second section}
\label{second}

\section{Third section}
\label{third}

\section{Fourth section}
\label{fourth}

\end{document}
```

References:

1. [What `\cs_new_protected` and `\cs_generate_variant` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515906/what-cs-new-protected-and-cs-generate-variant-do)
2. [What do ExplSyntaxOn and ExplSyntaxOff do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108696/what-do-explsyntaxon-and-explsyntaxoff-do)
3. https://github.com/textmate/latex.tmbundle/issues/79 expl3 syntax highlighting
4. http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf

Comment: You do not seem to generate `\user_name_refs:nnxn`, try adding `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_refs:nnnn { nnxn }`

Comment: @siracusa, after adding it, latex now throws the error **``Illegal parameter number in definition of \__seq_item:n``**

Comment: In the definition of `\user_name_refs:nnnn`, there's no argument `##2` for `\seq_map_inline:Nn`, that should be a `##1`

Comment: @siracusa, It worked! Thanks! Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by generating the proper function variant to be able to use `\user_name_refs:nnxn`:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \user_name_refs:nnnn { nnxn }
```

and by using the correct inline function parameter (`##1` instead of `##2`) in the defintion of `\user_name_refs:nnnn`:

```
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpa_seq
  {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__user_name_refs_tmpb_seq
                      { \user_name_ref:nn {#3} {##1} }
  }
```

Resulting PDF:

[image: Resulting PDF of the full compiled document]